# Calculation in columns using previous row value without loops

Tags: r

I have data in columns which I need to do calculations on. Is it possible to do this using previous row values without using a loop? E.g. if in the first column the value is 139, calculate the median of the last 5 values and the percent change of the value 5 rows above and the value in the current row?

```
ID  Data    PF
135 5       123
136 4       141
137 5       124
138 6       200
139 1       310
140 2       141
141 4       141
```

So here in this dataset you would do:

1. Find `139` in `ID` column
2. Return average of last 5 rows in `Data` (Gives `4.2`)
3. Return performance of values in `PF` 5 rows above to current value (Gives `152%`)

If I would do a loop it looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$ID == "139" & i>=3) 
    {data$New_column <- data[i,"PF"] / data[i-4,"PF"] - 1
}
```

The problem is that the loop takes too long due to to many data points. The ID 139 will appear several times in the dataset.

Many thanks.
Carlos

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: Check out `rollapply` in the `zoo` package.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by performance of values in PF 5 rows above current value? Its mean? Its median? In any case you don't have 5 rows above 139 just 4.

Comment: Sorry, you are right 4 columns above, the current value should be included

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Tutuchacn and Sotos, use the package `zoo` to get the `mean` of the `Data` in the last N rows (inclusive of the row) you are querying (assuming your data is in the data frame `df`):

```
library(zoo)

ind <- which(df$ID==139)                             ## this is the row you are querying
N <- 5                                               ## here, N is 5
res <- rollapply(df$Data, width=N, mean)[ind-(N-1)]
print(res)
## [1] 4.2
```

`rollapply(..., mean)` returns the rolling mean of the windowed data of `width=N`. Note that the index used to query the output from `rollapply` is lagged by `N-1` because the rolling mean is applied forward in the series.

To get the percent performance from `PF` as you specified:

```
percent.performance <- function(x) {
  z <- zoo(x)                                        ## create a zoo series
  lz <- lag(z,4)                                     ## create the lag version
  return(z/lz - 1)
}
res <- as.numeric(percent.performance(df$PF)[ind])
print(res)
## [1] 1.520325
```

Here, we define a function `percent.performance` that returns what you want for all rows of `df` for which the computation makes sense. We then extract the row we want using `ind` and convert it to a number.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
ntest=139
sol<-sapply(5:nrow(df),function(ii){#ii=6
  tdf<-df[(ii-4):ii,]
  if(tdf[5,1]==ntest)
    c(row=ii,aberage=mean(tdf[,"Data"]),performance=round(100*tdf[5,"PF"]/tdf[1,"PF"]-1,0))
})
sol<- sol[ ! sapply(sol, is.null) ] #remove NULLs
sol

[[1]]
        row     aberage performance 
        5.0         4.2       251.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a decent start:

```
mytext = "ID,Data,PF
135,5,123
136,4,141
137,5,124
138,6,200
139,1,310
140,2,141
141,4,141"

mydf <- read.table(text=mytext, header = T, sep = ",")

do.call(rbind,lapply(mydf$ID[which(mydf$ID==139):nrow(mydf)], function(x) {
    tempdf <- mydf[1:which(mydf$ID==x),]
    data.frame(ID=x,Data=mean(tempdf$Data),PF=100*(tempdf[nrow(tempdf),"PF"]-tempdf[(nrow(tempdf)-4),"PF"])/tempdf[(nrow(tempdf)-4),"PF"])
}))

ID     Data        PF
139 4.200000 152.03252
140 3.833333   0.00000
141 3.857143  13.70968
```

The idea here is: You take `ID`'s starting from 139 to the end and use the `lapply` function on each of them by generating a temporary data.frame which includes all the rows above that particular `ID` (including the `ID` itself). Then you grab the mean of the `Data` column and the rate of change (i.e. what you call performance) of the `PF` column.